How can I configure NextJS to build sequelize-typescript code reliably?
I’ve refactored my NextJS (14.1.0) app to move from using sequelize to using sequelize-typescript in the back end. While developing everything has been working fine and I’m ready to build and test the app, but there’s problems when running next build.
After running next build, everything compiles and I can boot up the app. However, as soon as I load the app I am getting sequelize errors as the compiled sequelize code is trying to retrieve data from columns that don’t exist in the models I setup. The generated SQL from sequelize is trying to access attributes (columns) that appear on models other than the one being queried. For example, when querying the TeamMember model it’s trying to select a client_id field which doesn't exist on this model or table. This leads me to believe that the models are getting scrambled during the build process.
Example model definition:
import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  CreatedAt,
  UpdatedAt,
  DeletedAt,
  AllowNull,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
  PrimaryKey,
  AutoIncrement
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import Person from './Person';
import Role from './Role';

@Table({ tableName: 'team_members' })
export default class TeamMember extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  team_member_id!: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Person)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  person_id!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Person)
  Person!: ReturnType<() => Person>;

  @ForeignKey(() => Role)
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  team_member_role_id!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Role)
  Role!: ReturnType<() => Role>;

  @CreatedAt
  created_at!: Date;

  @UpdatedAt
  updated_at!: Date;

  @DeletedAt
  deleted_at?: Date;
}


Model and DB initialisation:
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import pg from 'pg';
import 'dotenv/config';

import Person from './models/Person';
import User from './models/User';
import TeamMember from './models/TeamMember';
import Attestation from './models/Attestation';
import Client from './models/Client';
import ClientNote from './models/ClientNote';
import Conversation from './models/Conversation';
import Country from './models/Country';
import Comment from './models/Comment';
import DDQResponse from './models/DDQResponse';
import FinPromCost from './models/FinPromCost';
import FinPromReview from './models/FinPromReview';
import FinPromSubmission from './models/FinPromSubmission';
import FinPromTemplate from './models/FinPromTemplate';
import FourFrictionsResponse from './models/FourFrictionsResponse';
import Message from './models/Message';
import ReviewerAssignment from './models/ReviewerAssignment';
import Role from './models/Role';
import SLA from './models/SLA';
import UploadDocument from './models/UploadDocument';
import EventLog from '@/lib/db/models/EventLog';
import ResourceDocument from '@/lib/db/models/ResourceDocument';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  ...config,
  {
    logging: false,
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectModule: pg,
    models: [
      Person,
      Attestation,
      Client,
      ClientNote,
      Comment,
      Conversation,
      Country,
      DDQResponse,
      EventLog,
      FinPromCost,
      FinPromReview,
      FinPromSubmission,
      FinPromTemplate,
      FourFrictionsResponse,
      Message,
      ReviewerAssignment,
      ResourceDocument,
      Role,
      SLA,
      TeamMember,
      UploadDocument,
      User
    ]
  }
);

export {
  sequelize,
  Attestation,
  Client,
  ClientNote,
  Comment,
  Conversation,
  Country,
  DDQResponse,
  EventLog,
  FinPromCost,
  FinPromReview,
  FinPromSubmission,
  FinPromTemplate,
  FourFrictionsResponse,
  Message,
  Person,
  ReviewerAssignment,
  Role,
  SLA,
  TeamMember,
  UploadDocument,
  User
};


Error when trying to get a TeamMember:
column TeamMember.client_id does not exist
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/Alex/Code/project/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.6.1/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:283:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/Alex/Code/project/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.6.1/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:122:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/Alex/Code/project/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.6.1/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:35:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Alex/Code/project/node_modules/.pnpm/pg-protocol@1.6.1/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:524:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:561:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:512:3)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:392:5)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:189:23)
      at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    length: 119,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42703',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '564',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'parse_relation.c',
    line: '3716',
    routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
    sql: `SELECT "y"."person_id", "y"."cognito_id", "y"."first_name", "y"."last_name", "y"."email", "y"."phone_number", "y"."active", "y"."is_resource_page_acknowledged", "y"."created_at", "y"."updated_at", "y"."deleted_at", "TeamMember"."team_member_id" AS "TeamMember.team_member_id", "TeamMember"."person_id" AS "TeamMember.person_id", "TeamMember"."team_member_role_id" AS "TeamMember.team_member_role_id", "TeamMember"."created_at" AS "TeamMember.created_at", "TeamMember"."updated_at" AS "TeamMember.updated_at", "TeamMember"."deleted_at" AS "TeamMember.deleted_at", "TeamMember"."client_id" AS "TeamMember.client_id", "TeamMember->Role"."role_id" AS "TeamMember.Role.role_id", "TeamMember->Role"."role" AS "TeamMember.Role.role", "TeamMember->Role"."role_type" AS "TeamMember.Role.role_type", "TeamMember->Role"."created_at" AS "TeamMember.Role.created_at", "TeamMember->Role"."updated_at" AS "TeamMember.Role.updated_at", "TeamMember->Role"."deleted_at" AS "TeamMember.Role.deleted_at", "TeamMember->Role"."entity_id" AS "TeamMember.Role.entity_id" FROM "persons" AS "y" LEFT OUTER JOIN "team_members" AS "TeamMember" ON "y"."person_id" = "TeamMember"."person_id" AND ("TeamMember"."deleted_at" IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" AS "TeamMember->Role" ON "TeamMember"."team_member_role_id" = "TeamMember->Role"."role_id" AND ("TeamMember->Role"."deleted_at" IS NULL) WHERE ("y"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "y"."cognito_id" = '060232d4-6081-70b3-5efb-f1182bef997d') LIMIT 1;`,
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: `SELECT "y"."person_id", "y"."cognito_id", "y"."first_name", "y"."last_name", "y"."email", "y"."phone_number", "y"."active", "y"."is_resource_page_acknowledged", "y"."created_at", "y"."updated_at", "y"."deleted_at", "TeamMember"."team_member_id" AS "TeamMember.team_member_id", "TeamMember"."person_id" AS "TeamMember.person_id", "TeamMember"."team_member_role_id" AS "TeamMember.team_member_role_id", "TeamMember"."created_at" AS "TeamMember.created_at", "TeamMember"."updated_at" AS "TeamMember.updated_at", "TeamMember"."deleted_at" AS "TeamMember.deleted_at", "TeamMember"."client_id" AS "TeamMember.client_id", "TeamMember->Role"."role_id" AS "TeamMember.Role.role_id", "TeamMember->Role"."role" AS "TeamMember.Role.role", "TeamMember->Role"."role_type" AS "TeamMember.Role.role_type", "TeamMember->Role"."created_at" AS "TeamMember.Role.created_at", "TeamMember->Role"."updated_at" AS "TeamMember.Role.updated_at", "TeamMember->Role"."deleted_at" AS "TeamMember.Role.deleted_at", "TeamMember->Role"."entity_id" AS "TeamMember.Role.entity_id" FROM "persons" AS "y" LEFT OUTER JOIN "team_members" AS "TeamMember" ON "y"."person_id" = "TeamMember"."person_id" AND ("TeamMember"."deleted_at" IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN "roles" AS "TeamMember->Role" ON "TeamMember"."team_member_role_id" = "TeamMember->Role"."role_id" AND ("TeamMember->Role"."deleted_at" IS NULL) WHERE ("y"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "y"."cognito_id" = '060232d4-6081-70b3-5efb-f1182bef997d') LIMIT 1;`,
  parameters: {}


Is there anyway to adjust the next.config.js to handle this? I think SWC (the compiler) is having issues with transpiling the typescript decorators properly.
I've tried using Babel to compile the app, but it fails to compile the server actions. More on this issue and the error I'm seeing when trying this approach here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57966

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
